# How to compare all of the values of a map in Scala based on the value of a key which is input by the user?

Tags: scala, maps, comparison, key-value

I have functions which allow the user to compare two teams contained within a map. The data contained in the map is read in from a text file which contains information about football teams and their points tallies for the past 5 seasons. The data is stored as Map[String, List[Int]]:

```
Manchester United, 72, 86, 83, 90, 94
Manchester City, 80, 84, 91, 77, 88
Chelsea, 76, 85, 92, 87, 84
Arsenal, 70, 79, 81, 76, 83
Liverpool, 69, 77, 80, 73, 79
```

The functions below allow the user to enter the names of two teams and compare the difference between the most recent (last) points tallies for the two teams.

```
 val teamdata = readTextFile("teams.txt")

 //User presses 2 on keyboard, this invokes menuCompareTeams which invokes compareTeams
 def menuOptionTwo(): Boolean = {
   //2 - compare 2 teams selected by the user
   menuCompareTeams(compareTeams)
   true
 }

 //Function which displays the results of compareTeams
 def menuCompareTeams(f: (String, String) => ((String, Int), (String, Int), String)) = {
        val input = f(readLine("Enter first team to compare>"),
                      readLine("Enter second team to compare>"))
        println(s"""|Team 1: ${input._1._1} - Points: ${input._1._2}
                    |Team 2: ${input._2._1} - Points: ${input._2._2}
                    |${input._3}""".stripMargin)           
 }
   
 ///Function which compares the 2 teams - invoked by menuCompareTeams
 def compareTeams(team1: String, team2: String): ((String, Int), (String, Int), String) = {
   def lastPoints(list: List[Int]): Int = list match {
     case Nil => throw new Exception("Empty list")
     case h :: Nil => h
     case _ :: tail => lastPoints(tail)
   }

   val team1Points = teamdata.get(team1) match{
     case Some(p) => lastPoints(p)
     case None => 0
   }

   val team2Points = teamdata.get(team2) match{
     case Some(p) => lastPoints(p)
     case None => 0
   }

   val pointsComparison = if(team1Points > team2Points){
     "The team who finished higher is: " + team1 + ", their total points tally for last season was: " + team1Points + ". There was a difference of " + (team1Points-team2Points) + " points between the two teams."
   }
   else if(team1Points == team2Points){
     "The teams had equal points last season: " + (team1Points|team2Points)
   }
   else{
     "The team who finished higher is: " + team2 + ", their total points tally for last season was: " + team2Points + ". There was a difference of " + (team2Points-team1Points) + " points between the two teams."
   }

   ((team1, team1Points), (team2, team2Points), pointsComparison)
  
 }
```

E.g. The correct output for when the user enters 'Manchester United' and 'Manchester City' is shown below:

> Team 1: Manchester United - Points: 94
>
> Team 2: Manchester City - Points: 88
>
> The team who finished higher is: Manchester United, their total points tally for last season was: 94. There was a difference of 6 points between the two teams.

I now wish to allow the user to enter the name of one team and return a list containing the names of all the other teams within the map and whether they finished the season with more or less points than the user's selected team based on the most recent (last) points tally. E.g. if I was to input 'Chelsea', my expected output based on the last points tally for each team would be:

> Selected Team: Chelsea
>
> Manchester United - Finished the season with more points than selected team
>
> Manchester City - Finished the season with more points than selected team
>
> Arsenal - Finished the season with less points than selected team
>
> Liverpool - Finished the season with less points than the selected team

I am new to Scala and have tried a couple of different ways to do this, without success. How would I be able to adapt my code so that the user can enter the name of one team and the function will compare the selected team's last value with the last values of every other team and return the expected output shown above?

**EDIT:** This question has been identified as a possible duplicate of another question I asked earlier today, however, both questions are asking two different things. [Is there a better or functional way to compare 2 values in a map in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492630/better-or-functional-way-to-compare-2-values-in-a-map-in-scala)

Comment: You already asked this question today...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better or functional way to compare 2 values in a map in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492630/better-or-functional-way-to-compare-2-values-in-a-map-in-scala)

Comment: @TimP I did originally ask this question earlier today along with another question (in one "post"), however, based on a comment in reply to that question/"post", it was suggested that I break up the questions into separate questions("posts"). I have now done this. The question you suggested as a duplicate asks if there is a better or functional way of comparing 2 values based on the user's input. This question asks how I would be able to adapt my code to allow the user to enter one team and compare that team's value with _all_ of the other teams within the map.

Comment: @TimP I can edit my original question/"post" to make it the way it originally was, if required?